# Why does boxplot outline not change colour in ggplot / R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to apply the same outline color around the boxplot as the fill in my boxplot. The plot currently looks like this:

[image]

And was written with the following:

```
n <- ggplot(kirecur, aes(ki67in, time.yr, fill = factor(ki67in))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(ki67in, 1))) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="ki67in"))

n +     scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.6,0.1,0.2)) + 
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("forestgreen","red","orange")) +
        scale_colour_manual(values=c("forestgreen","red","orange"))
```

I added the `scale_colour_manual(values=c("forestgreen","red","orange"))`but that does not seem to work.

```
My data
kirecur <- structure(list(time.yr = c(0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.41666666666667, 
3.16666666666667, 3.25, 4.08333333333333, 4.41666666666667, 4.5, 
4.66666666666667, 4.75, 4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 5, 
6.16666666666667, 7.41666666666667, 7.5, 7.66666666666667, 9.83333333333333, 
10.3333333333333), ki67in = structure(c(1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 
0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("time.yr", "ki67in"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(16L, 
20L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 35L, 40L, 53L, 
54L, 60L, 64L, 65L, 67L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 87L, 111L, 112L, 
116L, 159L, 171L))
```

Comment: You need to map the same variable to `color` as you did to `fill`: `color = factor(ki67in)`.

Comment: Color only changes when you assign a variable to it. Color and fill are different aesthetics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize colour or alpha, you need to add the parameter `color =` and `alpha =` in your `ggplot()` call.

```
kirecur %>% 
  mutate(ki67in = factor(ki67in)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ki67in, time.yr, fill = ki67in, alpha = ki67in, color = ki67in)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(ki67in, 1))) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.6,0.1,0.2)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("forestgreen","red","orange")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("forestgreen","red","orange"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @demarsylvain. What if I wish outliers to have an alpha=1 but the fill at alpha=0.2?

Comment: for this, you can try to identify your outliers before to make the plot, add a variable in your kirecur dataset with 1 if outlier and 0 if not, and use this variable to define a different alpha.